# undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json if i add [Route] attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have my controller an my action method GetAvailabilitiesForPorducts. If i remove the Name property from the [HttpGet] attribute, this works fine. Everithing works even if i remove the [Route] attribute.

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/products")]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {

        [Route("availability")]
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetAvailabilitiesForPorducts")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AvailabilityDTO>>> GetAvailabilitiesForPorducts([FromQuery] AvailabilityResourceParams availabilityResourceParams)
        { ... }
```

I need Both attributes. I already checked, i do not have other actions with same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could input `https://localhost:xxxx/swagger/v1/swagger.json` in address bar when you debug to check the error

On myside, the error :

[image]

With your settings,two routes were registed:

default route :  `api/products/availability`

a new route parttern name of `GetAvailabilitiesForPorducts` : `api/products`

[image]

In fact,you could write your route parttern directly in the constructor of `HttpGet` Attribute ,fixed with

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/products")]
    public class MyApiController : ControllerBase
    {

        //[Route("availability")]
        [HttpGet("availability", Name = "GetAvailabilitiesForPorducts")]
        public IActionResult SomeAction()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Removing the [Route] attribute and using [HttpGet("availability", Name = "GetAvailabilitiesForPorducts")] i solved the problem!